# Chromium Android poor performance

Tags: android, build, chromium

I built Chromium browser successfully with the instructions (https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions) and it works fine. The only problem is that the performance is horrible. I even tried to build it with the option "arm64" in args.gn:

```
target_os = "android"
target_cpu = "arm64"
is_debug = true
enable_incremental_javac = true
```

The file is located in /src/out/Default which is where I built the apk files with this command

```
ninja -C out/Default chrome_public_apk
```

The animations are laggy and webpages are loading awfully slow. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building a debug binary, if you want a usable build set `is_debug = false` as that will enable release optimizations. This is enough to get acceptable performance though I think official builds are even more heavily optimized.

Comment: So how is that optimize_max actually used? Your documentation is no longer found :(

Comment: Looks like it's been removed, my guess is it wasn't actually used. All the GN docs are [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/tools/gn/docs), doesn't look like there's anything simple beyond making a release build but you could play with adding some heavily optimizing compiler/linker flags manually.

Comment: Ok I see. Do you know anything about the Google login problem? I can't add a gogle account as it goes to adding a new account to the device.

Comment: Sorry, I don't.